# Rewrite the query to use a single regexp_like operator

Tags: regex, oracle

can any one help me to write same query using `regexp_like` operator.(Please use `hr.employees`)

```
Select last_name from employees where 
Last_name like '%a%' and
Last_name like '%e%' and
Last_name like '%s%' ;
```

Thank you all for your valuable response.

Comment: I like  other's initially misread it to be `OR` instead of `AND`. The query you are using seems to be the correct way for this, and you don't need `REGEXP_LIKE`. You may just want to learn something from a solution with it, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want one line, you'd have to take

```
regexp_like(last_name, '(a.*b.*c)|(a.*c.*b)|(b.*a.*c)|(b.*c.*a)|(c.*a.*b)|(c.*b.*a)')
```

which is very unreadable.
I'd recommend using your initial approach with `like`s and `and`s.

Oracle regex is simple and doesn't provide i.e. positive lookaheads which make it simple in i.e. javascript for this conditions. In javascript this would be

```
^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)
```

Comment: Leading/trailing `.*` will make matching slower, remove them. REGEXP_LIKE does not require a full string match, so `'a.*b.*c|a.*c.*b|b.*a.*c|b.*c.*a|c.*a.*b|c.*b.*a'` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Rather simple:

```
regexp_like(Last_name, 'a') and 
regexp_like(Last_name, 'e') and 
regexp_like(Last_name, 's')
```

Comment: Thanks, 

But is there any otherway to use once regexp_like operator instead of 3 times.